# determine type of probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

let us consider following  model

$$y(t)=A_1 \sin(\omega_1 t+\phi_1) + A_2 \sin(\omega_2 t+\phi_2) + A_3 \sin(\omega_3 t+\phi_3)+ \ldots +A_p \sin(\omega_p t+\phi_p)+z(t)$$

we have  three parameter fixed,but unknown and also $z(t)$ is simple white noise, before i  will ask my question let us consider following situation,because parameters are fixed, that means that  sinusoidal components represents  deterministic model right?even more  if we know these parameters,then at some time $t=t_0$, we can consider  each model as scalar so we have  sum of scalars + random variable, because white noise are iid, does it means that sum also will be iid? let us consider following case,we have $p$ deterministic component,let us construct following  equation

$\alpha_{11}+\alpha_{12}+\cdots+\alpha_{1p}+z(1)$

$\alpha_{21}+\alpha_{22}+\cdots+\alpha_{2p}+z(2)$

$\vdots$

$\alpha_{n1}+\alpha_{n2}+\cdots+\alpha_{np}+z(n)$

we can consider it as

$$y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$$

now how can i estimate what is a probability distribution form of  $y_i$? let us suppose that original sinusoidal components are just harmonically related to each other,does it help us to determine distribution form of outcomes? what if they are not harmonically and ratio of two frequency can be irrational? i know there exist for example

- Markov process
- Lévy process
- A renewal process

and so on. how can i find relevant model for this process? thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to look at the problem of harmonic retrieval - things like Prony's method (or an extension known as Kuamresan-Tufts), Pisarenko, periodograms, Iterative Quadratic Maximum Likelihood (nice paper by Bresler and Mackovski - ML estimation of exponential signals in noise) or alternating projection  (see a paper by Ziskind and Wax on ML localization of sources via alternating projection). If these are coming from a sensor array, there are algorithms like MUSIC and ESPRIT to do things.

Comment: generally  detection of  frequencies may not be problem,let us assume that we know frequencies amplitudes and phases,how it will help me?

Comment: If you know everything but $z(t)$, then the distribution of $y(t)$ is determined completely by the deterministic portion. So, if $z(t)$ is iid $N(0,1)$, for example and the sum of sinusoids is $d(t)$, $y(t)$ is independent at different times and $y(t) \sim N(d(t), 1)$.

Comment: $N(0,1)$  means normal distribution right?standardized normal distribution,does  process will be normal distribution with mean $d(t)$ and variance  $1$?

Comment: Yes. All this is a known signal in additive noise if the parameters of the sinusoids are known (and the deterministic signal just shifts the noise signal). If the parameters of the sinusoids are not known, the problem is somewhat interesting and there is extensive literature on harmonic retrieval to estimate those parameters.

Comment: so does matter how frequencies are related to each other?i mean if they  are harmonically related,they are  creating normal distribution and if they are not harmonically related to each other,they are again normal distributed?

Comment: Doesn't matter how the frequencies are related. When $z(t)$ is i.i.d. $N(0,1)$, then the vector $[y(t_1),y(t_2),\ldots,y(t_n)]^T ~ N([d(t_1),d(t_2),\ldots,d(T_n)], I)$.

Comment: but if  white noise is not gaussian noise?

Comment: Similar deal. Its the joint distribution of $[d(t_1),d(t_2),\ldots,d(t_n)] + [z(t_1),\ldots,z(t_n)]$. The particular amplitude/phase/frequencies don't matter when they're known - only the noise statistics, which determine the joint distribution.

Comment: i mean,even noise is not gaussian,the process will be  normal right?

Comment: No, it would not be. I suggest you read a basic probability book then return to this question.

Comment: @Batman  i know  this basic  rules,white noise are independently  and uniformly distributed right?so  if i know  what is  probability distribution of  white noise,can i  define process type?